# How to get module size in 64Bit application?

Tags: c++, process, 64-bit

I am attempting to get a module's size in a C++ 64bit application, the code for that can be seen below.

```
MODULEENTRY32 me32; 
memset( &me32, 0x0, sizeof( MODULEENTRY32 ) );

DWORD base = (DWORD)me32.modBaseAddr;
DWORD moduleSize= (DWORD)me32.modBaseSize ;
```

I tested this with 32 bit successfuly but no luck on 64. Since its 64 bit I've figured that DWORD may not be enough to store values such as the entire module size.

After further reading I see that uintptr_t is more suited for such high values but since me32.modBaseSize returns DWORD I assumed it doesn't work for x64.

What alternative can I use to get the modBaseSize, is there an x64 version of this function or another way to return this information?

Comment: `modBaseSize` is already a `DWORD`, so no problems. `me32.modBaseAddr` is a pointer, so you can't put it in a `DWORD`

Comment: What method are you using to fill the `MODULEENTRY32`?

Comment: The 1st two lines of code is how ModuleEntry is being set, so if I wanted to store me32.modBaseAddr should casting it to uintptr_t work?

Comment: The first two lines are creating an empty `MODULEENTRY32`. I don't see anything that can set a value inside of it.

Comment: I suspect a 64-bit image still won't have modules larger than 4GB.

Comment: @MatsPetersson if it is, someone seriously needs to stop hiding full-length movies in their modules as easter eggs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting modBaseAddr to (DWORD) is not correct.  It is declared as BYTE*, pointer values are 8 bytes in 64-bit mode.  Do make sure you build to your code to x64 to get meaningful values for this field on a 64-bit operating system.

And yes, modBaseSize being a DWORD tells you that a module can never be larger than 4 gigabytes.  Even in 64-bit code.  Also visible from the [executable file format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64.SizeOfImage field is also still a DWORD.